# Filling Webform using selenium from excel via python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to fill webforms using selenium web driver in python language. thats not a tough task indeed but I am unable to find out how can fill the webform when the data must be taken from excel file.

I have tried selenium to fill webform that is possible and easy

rom selenium import webdriver

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chrome_driver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://admin.typeform.com/signup")
driver.find_element_by_id("signup_owner_alias").send_keys("Bruce Wayne")
driver.find_element_by_id("signup_owner_email").send_keys("bruce.wayne@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("signup_terms").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("signup_owner_language").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to fetch the data from your excel sheet. If you don't have it installed, you install it with pip: `pip install pandas`.

Below is an example of how data is fetched from an excel sheet using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('centuries.xls')

sheet_years = df['Year']

for year in sheet_years:
    print(year)
```

Basically, we fetched the excel sheet (centuries.xls) using the `read_excel()` method. Then we saved one of the columns ('Years' column in this example), in a variable (sheet_years). You can do same with other columns.

Rows in the saved column are automatically saved as list items, so we can iterate over these items using our `for` loop. You can replace it with your own code, instead of just printing the items in the list.

If your excel file contains more than one sheet, you can use the `sheet_name` parameter of the `read_excel()` method.

After doing the job with pandas, you can then send the output to your selenium code to fill the forms.

More information here:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html
- https://www.dataquest.io/blog/excel-and-pandas/

Comment: thats helps.. but when you use pandas , the data from excel is converted into dataframe and again manage the data from dataframe is additional task.